# Prevent children to be stopped by SIGTERM

Tags: bash, signals

I wrote this script (I removed some useless stuff):

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly ARGS="$@"

catch() {
    echo "Sigterm caught"
    # Perform some cleanup instructions
    # that suppose the child process is still alive
    trap - SIGTERM # remove the trap
    kill -s SIGINT -- -$$ # Sends SIGINT to child/sub processes
    exit 0
}

main() {

    trap "catch $5 $4" SIGTERM

    ./child_process_program # With all arguments needed

}

main $ARGS
```

I start this script with the script as follows: `timeout "10s" ./my_script <arguments>`.

The problem is that sigterm reaches also the child_process_program and so the instructions that suppose the child process is still alive cannot succeed.

I already see a [very similar question with answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156698/prevent-sigint-from-interrupting-function-call-and-child-processes-within) and tried (unsuccessfully) to change main as follows:

```
main() {

    trap "catch $5 $4" SIGTERM
    set -m
     ./child_process_program & # With all arguments needed

}
```

But I did not succeed. Is there a solution to my problem?